# How to mount SMB/CIFS Network Shares on android device?

Tags: networking, mount, file-sharing, cifs

I have a rooted android device running on gingerbread. I was wondering if there is a way to mount my windows CIFS(Common Internet File System) Shares on my android device over WiFi.

Is it required to have a kernel that supports CIFS protocol for mounting ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to be rooted and you have to have the kernel module for cifs support. if you have froyo, you also will need slow-work.ko kernel module as well.

Once you have those, you can use (shameless plug) [Mount Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.twimager.cifsmanager&hl=en), it can handle loading the modules for you automatically and lots of features available for auto mounting when connecting to wifi, and other stuff. It is a lot like Cifs Manager, but has a more robust system for loading the modules, and supports multiple modules and has support for being a plugin for locale/tasker (paid version).

Comment: I have android 2.3  and cifs.ko module is working on my device. Thanks. BTW, what is slow-work.ko?

Comment: slow-work is for froyo kernels. it contains some things that are missing in the kernel to allow cifs support. I am not 100% sure what, but I know if you have a froyo (2.2) device then you need that module along with cifs.ko

Comment: with its last update from 2011 does this even support android 4 or 5?

Comment: Mount Manager isn't available anymore

Comment: Any alternative to Mount Manager or CIFSManager currently available?

Answer (score 1):

download es file manager. add shared folder to it by scanning ur network.. video player built in even can put shortcut on desktop. I understand the advantages of what you are doing. it gets the job done without compiling and installing mods.: edit: only works with streaming file formats. copies file over otherwise

Comment: ES can't mount the network shares, but this is a good alternative.