# Mounting a remote folder as local folder

Tags: linux, mount, remote-control, ftp

I have spent hours researching this and unable to come up with a solution, if anyone knows of one please let me know. I am looking for a way to mount a remote folder on a server (using either WebDAV, FTP, etc) on my Android device as a local folder so that all apps can have access to it and save and read from it as if it were just any other folder on the phone or SD card. Note that I am not looking for a way to "sync" a folder on my phone with a folder on my server, everything in this folder should be stored on the server only and read as if it were local.

Answer (score 2):

On a rooted phone you have several options -- via 3rd party app, directly through a unix `mount` command, see [How to mount SMB/CIFS Network Shares on android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19107/how-to-mount-smb-cifs-network-shares-on-android-device)

If your phone is not rooted, I do not know how to do that, maybe there can be some app on a play store that is able to mount a network share (NFS, SMB, FTP, ...) via normal privileges (it is definetly possible under unix).

If you want to share just music and/or video you can use DLNA (your phone does not have to be rooted for this to work) -- install a DLNA server on your PC/router and than something like XBMC for Android or BubbleUPnp on your android device.

Answer (score 1):

I highly Do Not recommend doing this. It might cause the data on the remote server to be corrupted unless it is mounted as read-only. Android recognizing it as a remote file is much safer as it knows how to treat the file the right way when it is unexpectedly disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SSHFSAndroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chaos9k.sshfsandroid). Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same today.So maybe it is because some time has passed but Googling on "how to mount a webdav drive on Android" has a couple of pages with apps who do exactly that.

For example:

- [DAVx⁵](https://play.google.com/stor/apps/details?id=at.bitfire.davdroid) or
- [FolderSyncPro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full&hl=nl&gl=US)

I bought a license on FolderSyncPro and configured it to sync my data from my webdav drive to my Android folder. It works great. One thing to note here is that when you have a token for your webdav drive instead of a username or password then just ignore the username and fill in the token instead of the password.

You can also schedule it to sync on a schedule. Each sync will then show you either in green ok or in red when it encountered something and will then explain in the logs where the problem is.

It also allows for one-way only syncing so that you have your webdav as master and your android only as a read only instance for e.g. some data you only edit on laptops.

FYI the FAQ for FoldersyncPro: https://foldersync.io/docs/faq/webdav/

While investigating I also found https://www.resilio.com/individuals/, which takes a different direction and syncs directly from your system to your mobile devices. This may be an alternative route.